# Mac sample code for image Scale,Zoom,Pen and drag & drop

Tags: macos

Is there any sample code for image Scale,Zoom,Pen and drag & drop or reference in MAC?

Comment: Yes, there is. Where have you tried looking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Apple has enormous amounts of sample code on their developer website.
http://developer.apple.com/